# Find the sum of a Cos series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm using the following equation to generate a number series.

$v =-c\ \cdot \ \cos \left(\frac{t}{d}\cdot \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)+c\ +\ b$

Values I'm using to solve the series are:

$b = 0, c = 25, d = 25$ where $t$ = 0 to 100.

I know the sum of $v$ for the entire (100) series is 
$\left(c\cdot 20\right)\cdot \left(\frac{d}{5}\right)$

I have no idea where 20 and 5 come from; I just know the pattern holds true to any values for $c$ and $d$. Problem is I need to know the sum for any given $t$ value; not just $t$ = 100.

Is there a equation that will provide the sum of $v$ given any $t$. Example: If $t = 50$ the sum of $v$ will be $1275$ ... and so on.

Comment: Have you seen complex number before? Or more precisely Euler's formula?